# Can't connect to MySQL server and keep getting error: Unhandled exception: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I can not connect to MySql server and this is the error I keep getting:

Unhandled exception: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'TextBox_append_text_with_encoding'.

Possible C/C++ prototypes are:

```
mforms::TextBox::append_text_with_encoding(std::string const &,std::string const &,bool)
mforms::TextBox::append_text_with_encoding(std::string const &,std::string const &)
```

I just updated to High Sierra as I was running el capitan beforehand - I have tried reinstalling, deleting through terminal and downloading 5.6 version of MySql but nothing seems to be working.

Is there anyone who have any experience with the same error?

Comment: Can you post your connection code?

Comment: What is that? Do you mean the startup message log? I am a noob, sorry. Taking a course in SQL at uni.

Comment: What exactly are you doing, step by step, when you get this error? Which Workbench version do you have? These are not connection errors but something  from Python.

Comment: I am using the newest one 6.3.10. Step by step I am: 

1. opening a new connection

2. going into startup/shutdown

3. press start server where a window pops up requesting a password for service: sudo@localhost, user:gustavjandrup and I get: Executing 'launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist' in my startup message log

4. I type in the password and that is when I get the error message and I can not press the "start server" button unless I close the connection, go into home and open it again.

Comment: I tried changing to a different DB management system and am now trying with DBeaver and I get a different issue:

Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
  Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Connection refused (Connection refused)
    Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: I found a solution now for my workbench - I as not installing MySQL as admin ("sudo") so I launched dmg and reinstalled through terminal as sudo. MySql was installed properly and I was given a temporary password. It works now.